# Grabbing returned variables?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I have a model called Lead and a controller method called functions. Lead model has a method called grab.

```
def functions
    Lead.grab(data)
    puts newdata
end

def grab(data)
    newdata = data + 20
    return newdata
end
```

Why would this not work? The newdata variable is passed back but the functions method cannot seem to use it without an undefined error.

Comment: can you share the `undefined error`? Also did you mean  `def grab` instead of `def Lead` ?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `leads' for #<FunctionsController:0x588c660>

Answer (score 1):

You should have `newdata = Lead.grab(data)`.  The variable `newdata` in the grab function is out of scope of the controller, so you can't just use it. You have to set the variable in the controller to the returned value of `Lead.grab(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define a method called `Lead`. Do you mean `Lead.grab`?

I would expect it to be more like

```
class Lead

  def Lead.grab(data)
    ...
  end

end
```

When you call `functions`, there is nothing named `data`, so you probably get this error

```
undefined method or local variable, 'data'
```

That data variable has to come from somewhere. Perhaps

```
init_data = 30
data = Lead.grab(init_data)
puts data
# 50
```

Comment: Fixed the example. The problem is when the model method is called I don't know how to return a variable back to the controller that initially called it.

Comment: The grab method is returning the newdata value, but you're then not using it. So if you do `newdata = Lead.grab(data)` then `newdata` is the returned value. It's a local variable, so when you set it within the grab method it is not available outside that method as a variable, unless you set it as one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use self.grab(data)...end in Lead model

Here grab is an instance method not class and you are calling through model so make the grab a class method using self.